# ImputError: cannot import name "function" from "module.py"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp

In Jupyter Notebook:
repo:

- module: featurestorehouse.py
- main: preprocessing.ipynb

I have several functions in featurestorehouse.py, I need to import most of them, and some of them, particularly the ones I wrote earlier in time, work when I import them. However, the more recent ones don't want to be imported as it gives an ImputError.

I checked and changed where necessary, the necessary modules are imported in the module file, I tried putting the imports specific to a function within the function definition - which didn't fix anything, and I tried to not import the functions separately but adding 'fs.' in front of each to reference featurestorehouse as fs.

The function and module:

```
# # Feature Engineering #

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import spacy
import re
import string
from statistics import mean
from collections import Counter
```

Some of the functions that do not work:

```
# Phrasal complexity
## reference to Martinez (2018)

def nr_np(series):
    """Calculates nr of noun chunks in the texts."""
    nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
    text = nlp(series)
    nps = []
    for nc in text.noun_chunks:
        nps.append(np)
    return len(nps)

def count_np(df, word_count_column, np_count_column):
    """Divides number of words by number of noun phrases."""
    try:
        rel_np = df[word_count_column]/df[np_count_column]
        return rel_np
    except 'ZeroDivisionError':
        return '0'

def count_np_words(df, np_count_column, word_count_column):
    """Divides number of noun phrases by number of words."""
    try:
        rel_np = df[np_count_column]/df[word_count_column]
        return rel_np
    except 'ZeroDivisionError':
        return '0'
```

How I tried to implement them in my main notebook:

```
# Adding Custom Feature Columns
from featurestorehouse import avg_sentlength, avg_wordlength, nr_deps, count_deps, nr_verbs, count_verbs, nr_words, nr_sents, normalize, normalize_fix, nr_np, count_np, count_np_words, nr_clauses, rel_nr_clauses, rel_nr_words_clauses, unique_words, lexical_variety

## extract relevant column as series
series = df['fulltext'].astype(str)

# Sentence Complexity

## sentence length
df['sentence_cnt'] = series.apply(lambda x: nr_sents(x))

## average sentence length
df['avg_sentlength'] = series.apply(lambda x: avg_sentlength(x))


## POS distributions
### extract relevant column as series
series = df['POS'].astype(str)

### apply function
df['VERB_cnt'] = series.apply(lambda x: nr_verbs(x))
fs.count_verbs(df, 'TAG', 'VERB_cnt')


# Phrasal Complexity

## NP distributions
### extract relevant column as series
series = df['fulltext'].astype(str)

### apply function
df['NP_cnt'] = series.apply(lambda x: nr_np(x))
df['np_rel_cnt'] = count_np(df, 'word_cnt', 'NP_cnt')
df['np_rel_word_cnt'] = count_np_words(df, 'NP_cnt', 'word_cnt')
```

The last set underneath "### apply function" gives an error when I import featurestorehouse.py as fs and add fs. to each function in the main notebook (obviously it doesn't get to this point when I'm importing each function separately from featurestorehouse.py).

The error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-8ad058b0250d> in <module>
      1 # Adding Custom Feature Columns
----> 2 from featurestorehouse import avg_sentlength, avg_wordlength, nr_deps, count_deps, nr_verbs, count_verbs, nr_words, nr_sents, normalize, normalize_fix, nr_np, count_np, count_np_words, nr_clauses, rel_nr_clauses, rel_nr_words_clauses, unique_words, lexical_variety
      3 
      4 ## extract relevant column as series
      5 series = df['fulltext'].astype(str)

ImportError: cannot import name 'nr_np' from 'featurestorehouse' (C:\Users\tdems\Jupyter\CEFR_AES_dissertation\featurestorehouse.py)
```

Does anyone know what's up with this? There's no circular dependencies involved as far as I know. There's a lot of other notebooks in the repo but that's never been a problem up till now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure your notebook always loads the latest version after each change and not a cached version:

At the top of your notebook - before your imports - enter:

`%load_ext autoreload`

and in a new cell below:

`%autoreload 2`

Then restart your kernel and try again.

Comment: Restarting and adding the lines of code has fixed the problem, thank you. Now I know what to do next time as wel.

Comment: Apologies, I first time :)

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't work, an easy way in Jupyter is to use

```
%run Path_To_The_Other_File.ipynb
```

It will just execute the full Jupyter file refered by Path, so if you define a funtion, it will now be known in your main file